# Is it possible to create a subgraph in mermaid without any content in it?

Tags: flowchart, subgraph, mermaid

I want to create a subgraph in mermaid without any content in it.

The closest I came to was:

```
flowchart TB
subgraph Graph
 A[]
end
```

Which created the subgraph with a empty square in it.
So is it possible for me to create that without a square?

Comment: Im confused as to what you are trying to do here.  If there is no content, why would you want a subgraph?